# Not able to store functions value in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store `data.ip` value in ipdata variable.

`alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip)` is showin proper ip address value but `alert(ipdata)` is showing undefined

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var ipdata;

    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
        function(data){
            ipdata=data.ip;
            alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);  
        }); 
        alert(ipdata);
    });

});
```

Comment: `getJSON` is async, the complete callback is called after `alert(ipdata);` is executed.

Comment: So how can I get Ip address of client

Answer (score 2):

It will not work as expected because you are assigning `ipdata=data.ip;` inside a ajax call's callback method. Ajax calls are asynchronous in nature means once the request is sent to the server the `alert(ipdata);` will get executed before the ajax callbacl function is executed.

So any processing you want to do with `ipdata` has to be done within the callback function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var ipdata;

    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
        function(data){
            ipdata=data.ip;
            alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);  
            alert(ipdata);
        }); 
    });

});
```

Comment: So how to get Ip address of client

Comment: Do you want to store the ip address in a global variable for later use>

Answer (score 1):

You are using AJAX A for asynchronus. alert (ipdata) is evaluated before $.getJson function finishes! Either use Synchronus requests of learn how to use jquery defferend.

Something like **(NOT TESTED)**

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
        ipdata=data.ip;
        alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);  
    }); 
}).done(function (){
    alert(ipdata);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronus -

```
ipdata=data.ip;
alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
```

is executed after `alert(ipdata);`
 That is the reason `ipdata` didn't get updated

You can take a look at this question -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

The getJSON function is running asynchronously, so alert(ipdata) is running before the callback is fired.  If you moved alert(ipdata) inside the callback, you would see that it prints the proper IP address.

Answer (score 0):

As t.niese says above, alert(ipdata) will be called before ipdata=data.ip, as $.getJSON is asynchronous.

You need to put code that relies on the json response inside the callback, or you could try defining a separate function and calling it inside the json callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var ipdata;
    var finishedJsonLoad = function() {
        alert(ipdata);
    };

    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
        ipdata=data.ip;
        alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
        finishedJsonLoad();

    });

});
```